# Insert an Url into a bitmap

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I need, if is possible, to put a link in a text create with DrawString inside a shape that also was create with DrawRectangle. This is made in asp.net. Anyone know the way to do that or even is it possible. 
Tahnk

Comment: `This is made in asp.net`  In that case, probably the easiest thing to do is just include the link itself on the page, and use css styling to layer the text over top of your image.

Comment: The DrawString function just literally draws text. It has no concept of a link. Once the function finishes, it doesn't even have any concept of text. You can't retrieve the original string except by using something like OCR. All you have is a Bitmap. So like Joel implies, DrawString is the wrong function to be using.

Comment: Well, but i create something like "canvas" (not really) on the fly, and i put a series of image in there and i need to put a link for every image in there

Comment: I agree with @JoelCoehoorn that this should be solved with CSS.  What does your ASPX or HTML markup look like for a single element and link?

Comment: The first thing that i try is to create a serious number of div and put a link. This work find with Chrome and Safari, but it does not over IE. So now i use a draw... to create an image on the fly. I can not atach a file to comment, but is something like a mesh or net to put visual data

Comment: Not Yuck is serious number of element, and the client use IE

Comment: just want to clear things up. Do you want to simply 'watermark' the image with a URL (non-clickable) or actually creating a clickable link on the image? Or is it actually an image or just a rectangular shape containing a text or URL? Are you actually creating a clickable link but in bitmap intead og normal html text?

Comment: No, ajakblackgoat, i need a link to represent that singular part, the data containing in that singular part. Its something likx X,Y with serious number of data that represent a general description, but when you click in the link you go to that singular data. It's clear ? Let me know